# How to use jQuery to access DOM object passed to JavaScript function

Tags: jquery

I have multiple forms on one page where the form DOM object is being passed as an arugument to a JavaScript function like:

```
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <input id="textfield1" type="text" name="textfield1">
      <input id="textfield2" type="text" name="textfield2">
      <input id="textfield3" type="text" name="textfield3">
      <input name="button" type="button" id="btn" value="Get Info" onClick="getdata(this.form)">
    </form><form name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <input id="textfield1" type="text" name="textfield1">
  <input id="textfield2" type="text" name="textfield2">
  <input id="textfield3" type="text" name="textfield3">
  <input name="button" type="button" id="btn" value="Get Info" onClick="getdata(this.form)">
</form>
<form name="form3" method="post" action="">
  <input id="textfield1" type="text" name="textfield1">
  <input id="textfield2" type="text" name="textfield2">
  <input id="textfield3" type="text" name="textfield3">
  <input name="button" type="button" id="btn" value="Get Info" onClick="getdata(this.form)">
</form>

function getdata(form){
  alert("the value is: " + form.getElementById('textfield1).value);
}
```

How would I access the DOM object, passed in getdata(form), with jQuery?

I've tired $(form) but that only seems to access the button object, not other inputs in the form.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`$(form)` should indeed give you a jQuery reference to the form, whereas simply `form` will be the DOM node itself. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dx5c6/)

For what you're trying to acheive, though, you might be better off passing a DOM node as context to your selector:

```
$('#li_address', form).val()
```

However, since you're getting an element by ID, you won't need context – because you only have one, right? But a reasonable demo of using the DOM node as context is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dAuEQ/).

Since you're working with jQuery, though, you might want to switch from `onClick` and handle the event binding in jQuery as well. Note that I'm accessing all buttons with `.btn` assuming `class="btn"` rather than `id="btn"`. Again, ID should be unique in the entire document. Do not deviate from this. It'll bite you.

```
$('form .btn').click(function() {
    // this = button DOM node
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.submit(); // or whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns the DOM elements for form1

```
$('form[name=form1]').get()
```

or for all the forms

```
$('form').get()
```

To access individual form elements you can access for example button

```
$('form[name=form1] #btn')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in getData function like this-

```
form.fieldName.value
```